# CSS - Two different backgrounds on two pages

Tags: html, css, web, background

I want to make my homepage with `bg 1.jpg` and for the `www.blabla.com/second` I want another background.

I was looking for some code for this and I found this:

```
body { background: url("../1.jpg"); }
body.second { background-image: url("../2.jpg"); }
```

I cant use this, can you help me ? It uses `div` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1: 
Home page ->

```
<body class="home-page"> some content </body>
```

step 2:
Other pages - >

```
<body class="other-page"> some content </body>
```

step 3:
write some css like below

```
body.home-page {background:url('../1.jpg') no-repeat;}
```

```
body.other-page {background:url('../2.jpg') no-repeat;}
```

Comment: If I want it in WP or Joomla? It is possible?

Comment: change the <body> line to <br> <body <?php body_class($class); ?>>     [link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-the-body-class-name-for-a-page)

Comment: i am not good at php. pls refer this link [http://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-the-body-class-name-for-a-page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-the-body-class-name-for-a-page)

Answer (score 1):

Create a different body class for each page that you want with a different bg image:

```
<body class="homepage"></body>
<body class="secondpage"></body>
<body class="thirdpage"></body>
```

For your CSS:

```
body.homepage {background:url('bg1.jpg');}
body.secondpage {background:url('bg2.jpg');}
body.thirdpage {background:url('bg3.jpg');}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add wrapper divs around your document and give them a background-color. Then you just write to your stylesheet:

```
#wrapper1 {
background-image: ...;
}
#wrapper2{
background-image: ...;
}
```

html for the first document is like this:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id=wrapper1>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```